# Python: Dictionary infinitely loops code when entry is called

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a text adventure game in python, and I am  required to use a dictionary. I currently have it set up like this:

```
print("type A for option A, type B for option B.")


def introduction():
  upnext()  

  
def optionb():
  print("Welcome to option B!")


def optiona():
  print("welcome to option A!")
  print("type 1 for option 1!")
  upnext() 
  
def option1():
  print("this is option 1!")
  upnext() 
  
upnext = 0
dict = {"B" : optionb, "A" : optiona,
"1" : option1 }
upnext = dict[input()]

introduction()
```

When I hit run, the first print line prints properly, but when I type A to go to option A, the code in "optiona" runs infinitely. Option B works fine. How  should I make it so that the text prints once and then lets me move on to the next set of options?

Comment: Why have `upnext()` at the end of `option1`? `upnext` *is* `optiona`, so that function is endlessly recursive. Why not just put the 5 lines at the bottom inside a loop?

Comment: The desired behavior is not well-defined, let's say you finished handling option A, what would you like to be "next" state?

Comment: Unsurprising. Your `optiona()` function calls `upnext()` as the last line. So if `upnext` has been set to `optiona`, then infinite recursion here we come!

Comment: To clarify: This is a small snippet of what will be a larger game. upnext() is at the end of option1 as well because it is at the end of every function except those that end the game. I want upnext() to update to the next input after each question is asked so the game can keep going.